# NodeJS 7: How to Show the Correct Stack Trace in Async Mongoose Promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, error-handling

When I have an error in `mongoose` promises with `bluebird`. I don't have the correct line number, which makes it hard for me to find the error.

```
unknownFunction("A")#show me the correct line number in the trace
async.timesSeries 100,
  (index, next) ->
     unknownFunction("B") #show me only the line number where I catch the error

process.on 'uncaughtException', (err)->
  console.log err.stack
  console.trace err 
  throw err
```

Question: How can I get the correct line number instead of the line number where the error is catched?

PS: I found and tried this so far:
https://github.com/groundwater/node-stackup 
But it gives me a lot of unrelated line numbers.

### EDIT:

This is how I init mongoose with bluebird:

```
Promise = require("bluebird")
Promise.config({
  longStackTraces: true
  warnings: {
    wForgottenReturn: false
  }
})
mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = Promise
mongoose.set('error', true)
```

#### Example correct:

[image]

```
  ReferenceError: unknownFunction is not defined

  - patient.update.js:267
```

#### Example incorrect:

[image]

```
somepath/.tmp/serve/server.js:294
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: unknownFunction2 is not defined
```

The error is in `patient.update.js` line nr 268

#### Longjohn

With `longjohn`

```
somepath/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:192
        throw e;
        ^

ReferenceError: unknownFunction2 is not defined
```

#### Stack up

This is what I mean with `node-stack-up` unrelated lines (same test with `unknownFunction2`):

```
    /somepath/myApp/.tmp/serve/server.js:296
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: unknownFunction2 is not defined

    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - index.js:126 Kareem.execPost
    [myApp]/[kareem]/index.js:126:20

  - index.js:251 
    [myApp]/[kareem]/index.js:251:15

  - query.js:1616 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/query.js:1616:5

  - document.js:317 model.Document.init
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/document.js:317:5

  - query.js:1609 completeOne
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/query.js:1609:10

  - query.js:1271 Immediate.<anonymous>
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/query.js:1271:13

  - utils.js:137 Immediate.<anonymous>
    [myApp]/[mquery]/lib/utils.js:137:16

  - timers.js:649 runCallback
    timers.js:649:20

  - timers.js:622 tryOnImmediate
    timers.js:622:5

  - timers.js:594 processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
    timers.js:594:5


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - pool.js:454 handleOperationCallback
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:454:24

  - pool.js:490 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:490:9

  - pool.js:429 authenticateStragglers
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16

  - pool.js:463 Connection.messageHandler
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5

  - connection.js:309 Socket.<anonymous>
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/connection.js:309:
    22

  - events.js:96 emitOne
    events.js:96:13

  - events.js:188 Socket.emit
    events.js:188:7

  - _stream_readable.js:176 readableAddChunk
    _stream_readable.js:176:18

  - _stream_readable.js:134 Socket.Readable.push
    _stream_readable.js:134:10

  - net.js:551 TCP.onread
    net.js:551:20

  - glue.js:188 TCP.onread
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:188:31


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:88 Socket.connect
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:88:29

  - net.js:74 Object.exports.connect.exports.createConnection
    net.js:74:35

  - connection.js:389 Connection.connect
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/connection.js:389:
    11

  - pool.js:1059 _createConnection
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1059:14

  - pool.js:1151 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1151:13

  - pool.js:1082 waitForAuth
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1082:39

  - pool.js:1090 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1090:5

  - pool.js:957 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:957:21

  - glue.js:188 
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:188:31

  - next_tick.js:67 _combinedTickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7

  - next_tick.js:98 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - pool.js:956 Pool.write
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:956:13

  - cursor.js:288 CommandCursor.Cursor._find
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:288:22

  - cursor.js:588 nextFunction
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:588:10

  - cursor.js:696 CommandCursor.Cursor.next [as _next]
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:696:3

  - cursor.js:849 fetchDocs
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/cursor.js:849:10

  - cursor.js:876 toArray
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/cursor.js:876:3

  - cursor.js:829 CommandCursor.Cursor.toArray
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/cursor.js:829:44

  - db.js:1662 indexInformation
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/db.js:1662:39

  - db.js:1626 Db.indexInformation
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/db.js:1626:44

  - db.js:1129 ensureIndex
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/db.js:1129:8

  - db.js:1105 Db.ensureIndex
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/db.js:1105:44

  - collection.js:1891 ensureIndex
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/collection.js:1891:13

  - collection.js:1879 Collection.ensureIndex
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/collection.js:1879:44

  - collection.js:126 NativeCollection.(anonymous function) [as ensureIndex]
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:12
    6:28

  - model.js:1019 create
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/model.js:1019:22

  - model.js:1033 Immediate.<anonymous>
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/model.js:1033:7

  - timers.js:649 runCallback
    timers.js:649:20

  - timers.js:622 tryOnImmediate
    timers.js:622:5

  - timers.js:594 processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]
    timers.js:594:5


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - _stream_writable.js:377 onwrite
    _stream_writable.js:377:15

  - _stream_writable.js:90 WritableState.onwrite
    _stream_writable.js:90:5

  - net.js:724 Socket._writeGeneric
    net.js:724:5

  - net.js:734 Socket._write
    net.js:734:8

  - _stream_writable.js:334 doWrite
    _stream_writable.js:334:12

  - _stream_writable.js:320 writeOrBuffer
    _stream_writable.js:320:5

  - _stream_writable.js:247 Socket.Writable.write
    _stream_writable.js:247:11

  - net.js:661 Socket.write
    net.js:661:40

  - connection.js:500 Connection.write
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/connection.js:500:
    53

  - pool.js:1137 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1137:26

  - pool.js:1082 waitForAuth
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1082:39

  - pool.js:1090 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:1090:5

  - pool.js:957 
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:957:21

  - glue.js:188 
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:188:31

  - next_tick.js:67 _combinedTickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7

  - next_tick.js:98 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - pool.js:956 Pool.write
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/connection/pool.js:956:13

  - cursor.js:288 Cursor._find
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:288:22

  - cursor.js:588 nextFunction
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:588:10

  - cursor.js:696 Cursor.next [as _next]
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb-core]/lib/cursor.js:696:3

  - cursor.js:672 nextObject
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/cursor.js:672:8

  - cursor.js:262 Cursor.next
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/cursor.js:262:12

  - collection.js:1401 findOne
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/collection.js:1401:10

  - collection.js:1387 Collection.findOne
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/[mongodb]/lib/collection.js:1387:44

  - collection.js:126 NativeCollection.(anonymous function) [as findOne]
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:12
    6:28

  - node.js:38 NodeCollection.findOne
    [myApp]/[mquery]/lib/collection/node.js:38:19

  - mquery.js:1787 model.Query.Query.findOne
    [myApp]/[mquery]/lib/mquery.js:1787:20

  - query.js:1260 model.Query.Query._findOne
    [myApp]/[mongoose]/lib/query.js:1260:22

  - index.js:239 
    [myApp]/[kareem]/index.js:239:8

  - index.js:18 
    [myApp]/[kareem]/index.js:18:7

  - glue.js:188 
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:188:31

  - next_tick.js:67 _combinedTickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7

  - next_tick.js:98 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9


    ---- async ----

  - glue.js:150 asyncWrap
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:150:28

  - glue.js:401 wrapCallback
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/glue.js:401:35

  - index.js:16 process.nextTick
    [myApp]/[async-listener]/index.js:16:26

  - index.js:17 Kareem.execPre
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on the wrong hunch (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1297).

This issue was not related to `nodejs` it was a mongoose bug which is closed in a newer version https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4209. In older versions it seemed to be required to catch the error at the end of the mongoose query.

Solution:

```
PatientModel.findOne(newFilterUpdate).exec((err, patient) ->
    ...
).catch (err)->
    console.log "err #{err}"
```

or upgrading `mongoose`

Answer (score 4):

The node-stackup, [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn), and [Bluebird's long stack traces](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/environment-variables.html) are the best solutions available. I'm not sure what you mean by "it gives me a lot of unrelated line numbers." It's giving you a stack trace, so unless you've written **all** the code and have zero dependencies then you're bound to see function calls to lines you didn't write regardless of whether the operation is asynchronous or not.

Essentially what these libraries do is just stitch detached stack traces together. Normally JavaScript stack traces won't include anything involving an asynchronous operation, only the most recent synchronous function calls. These libraries monkey patch most methods that can introduce asynchronous behavior (process.nextTick, setTimeout, EventEmitter, etc.). They add code which creates a new stack trace at each of these call sites and stores all of these until an error occurs. It will join all of the stored stack traces together so you can actually walk back through all of the asynchronous operations until you get to the original call site.

Comment: I added an edit. I tried it with `longjohn` but it does not show me the correct line number. The bluebird long stack traces I had already before, which do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following tool **[decofun debug tool](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/decofun#install)** to *deanomise* the anonymous functions.

*Complete details mentioned in the following answer written by me in this*

> [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382944/6606831)

The documentation is as mentioned [here](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/decofun#install)

Comment: Thx, I tried it with requiring the module (before/after server start, in the file) but I didn't change anything. The cmd line version I can't test, I have too many build processes, configurations etc. before it wouldn't integrate well.

Answer (score 0):

For any uncaughtException the server will stop in order to make the server keep on running even when there is an uncaught exception what i have done is created a separate collection for storing error, save error once an uncaught exception occurs and returns.

**Collection**

```
var ErrorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  err_Message:{type:String},
  err_Stack:{type:String},
  date:{type:Date}
});
```

**Controller**

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);

    var newError = new Error;
    newError.err_Message = err.message;
    newError.err_Stack = err.stack;
    newError.date = moment();
    newError.save(function(saveErr,errData){
        if(!saveErr)
            console.log('New Error is saved');
        else
            console.log('Error in saving error');
    });
    //process.exit(1)
});
```

The above methods stores the uncaught exception in the *Error* collection and the process/server does not stops.

**Reference**: Already answered in [Nodejs debug errors in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144288/nodejs-debug-errors-in-production/41441063#41441063)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I bascially have the same wihtout storing it in the database. The problem is, that the `err` error object is already refereing to the wrong line number. It is referring to the line where `process.on` is called instead of the error line.

Comment: Its strange that js displays wrong line number on process.on('error') http://juan-gandhi.livejournal.com/942493.html

Try this and check if shows the correct line number

Comment: I get `return st2(f.caller).concat([f.toString().split('(')[0].substring(9) + '(' + f["arguments"].join(',') + ')']);
                                                                                                    ^

  TypeError: f.arguments.join is not a function`. I'm passing the err form `process.on` to `stacktrace` even if it does not require an argument.